# Find the probability of rolls an 8 with a fair pair of dice using law of total probability.

Tags: probability

I came accross this problem and was confuse why P(E|Fi) = 1/6 when i = 2,3,4,5,6
Shouldn't P(E|Fi) = 1/5 since i = 1 cannot complete a sum of 8 with any given Fi?,

Find the probability of rolls an 8 with a fair pair of dice using law of total probability.

```
Fi = {1st fie equals i} , i = 1 , ... , 6
```

and `P(E|Fi) = 1/6, i = 2,3,4,5,6 while P(E|F1) = 0`

```
Thus P(E) = (5/36); 

P(EFi) = 1/36, i = 2, ... , 6
       = 0, i = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of $P(E | F_i)$ is the probability that $E$ occurs given that $F_i$ occurs.

Now I can see your reasoning as follows: You are saying that $ 1 =  P(E  | F_1) + P(E | F_2) + \ldots + P(E | F_6)$. You probably think this is because *one of the* $F_i$ *has to happen*, and therefore if $E$ has happened, then one of the $F_i$ has surely happened before it. But $F_1$ cannot happen, so the probability of all the others is $\frac{1}{5}$.

However, this is not correct. The reason for that is the following inequality:

$$P (A | (B \cup C))  = \frac{P(A \cap (B \cup C))}{P(B \cup C)}\neq \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} +  \frac{P(A \cap C)}{P(C)} = P(A | B) + P(A | C)$$.

You can see why just from definition of $|$ notation.

Now, $F_1 \text{ or } F_2 \ ... \text{ or } F_6$ occurs with probability $1$, however, it is not true that $P( E | (F_1 \text{ or } F_2 ... \text{ or } F_6)) = P(E | F_1) + P(E | F_2) + \ldots + P(E| F_6)$. Hence your thinking is wrong.

Therefore, the answer $\frac{5}{36}$ comes purely from working by definition.

I know this is confusing. If you want a clearer explanation, please demand it.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have already rolled the first die.  If it is a $1$, then there is no chance of rolling the second die to get a sum of $8$.  Otherwise, there is a $1/6$ chance that when you roll the second die, your sum will be $8$.  That is why it is $1/6$ instead of $1/5$.